# Git Added 100 of commits from other branches into my branch after rebase

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using GitLab. I was trying to rebase my branch. I ran `git pull --rebase` from my branch. Then I ran `git push -u origin mybranch` and `git push`. It ran successfully but it added 100 of commits into my Merge(Pull) request and mess up my all work. What should I do now. I just wanna get rid these commits from my branch and Merge(Pull) request.

Comment: I just reset the HEAD to my last known commit and rebase my branch again. Finally, push my branch every work as expected